# Multiple ssh IDs & localhost Confusion

Tags: bash, ssh, iterm

I've been operating on a single `local` `ssh` ID for some time.  I connect to servers on my `LAN` after copying my **public key** to them for future quick connects.  Worked fine.

I have a `Github` account that was created before I set up my `CLI` `Github` setup only recently.  Because my domestic username or `email` **rich@mybox.local** doesn't match my `Github` email/ID, I had to use `ssh_add` to create a second ID for myself for using `git`.

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_git
```

Now I have to IDs in `~/.ssh/` and now connecting to my normal servers doesn't function properly, as it asks for a password every time.  The previous setup with a single ID assumed the single entry would suffice.

Questions:

1. Is this normal/expected?  It's possible it's confused since there is more than one possible public key to send.
2. Can I fix this?  Set up something that my `git` ID is only used for `git`? Fix might not be the word, but **arrange**?

I wasn't expecting this, but I don't see any way around it.  I'm using `iTerm` so maybe there's something in there that might allow me to choose one public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a permissions issue on `~/.ssh`.  Also, commands might need to include the specific `public key` as well as `config` setup.